# Factorization of a dataset with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I'm very new in Python. I have a pandas dataframe:

```
d={'col1': [100000, 939321, 28923,100000], 'col2': [-11234, 114567,21234,-11234]}               
mydata=pandas.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Now I want to convert this dataframe in factor, to get `[1,2,3,1]` and `[1,2,3,1]`.

I tried with:

```
from collections import Counter
mydata.col1.factorize(list(range(Counter(mydata.col1.factorize))),sort=True)
```

But I get:

```
factorize() got multiple values for argument 'sort'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling `factorize` as a member function of a `pandas.Series` object (in your case you call it from `mydata.col1`). In that case the first argument of the function call is the `sort` option, while you pass it another `pandas.Series`. For the detailed signature of the function see

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html

What I suspect you were trying to do is to call the `factorize` function of the `pandas` module. In this case the first argument of the call is a `pandas.Series` and the second is the `sort` option

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.factorize.html

Then the last line of your code would look something like

```
pandas.factorize(mydata.col1, sort=True)
```

**P.S**
I suspect that you want to access the first element of the above as

```
pandas.factorize(mydata.col1, sort=True)[0]
```